# How do I clear Google Chrome's DNS cache entirely?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dns

Chrome is quite aggressive about caching HTTP responses. I assume this is for speed.

However, for a web developer such as myself, this can often be problematic, since pages I work on often change a lot.

For instance, my company's public website had a connection problem that I fixed but Chrome still gives me a `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` page whenever I visit it (the root domain and every URL under it). If I use any other browser, or Incognito mode it works. Also visiting subdomains works.

I've tried the following:

1. Restarting Chrome
2. [Clearing browser data](http://chrome://settings/clearBrowserData)
3. Going to chrome://net-internals/#dns and clearing host cache
4. Going to chrome://net-internals/#sockets and flushing socket pools
5. Closing all tabs and restarting
6. All or some of the above and flushing the OS DNS cache with: `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;`

On my colleagues' Windows computers, simply clearing host cache in Chrome works.

I'm using Chrome 52.0.2743.49 beta on El Capitan / 10.11.5 (Btw: Have had the same problem with non-beta Chrome in the past)

Any advise?

Answer (score 2):

Just clear the "Cached images and files" in step 2 works for my Chrome on Mac Sierra most of the time, sometimes I need add step 3 and 4.