# Chrome refuses to flush / refresh DNS—why?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dns, mamp

On OSX El Capitan, I have an issue developing a Wordpress site hosted locally by MAMP. When I visit the root hostname specified in MAMP, Chrome redirects me to an old hostname I previously used for the same site. Non-root URLs work ok. Every browser other than Chrome (FF, Canary, Safari) all correctly resolve the current hostname. Only Chrome refuses to resolve the new host.

Steps I've tried so far:

- Restarting Chrome
- Clearing browser data
- Going to `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and clearing host cache
- Going to `chrome://net-internals/#sockets` and flushing socket pools
- Closing all tabs and restarting
- Flushing the OS DNS cache with: `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo
  killall -HUP mDNSResponder;`

(yes, those are the same steps listed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244095/how-do-i-clear-google-chromes-dns-cache-entirely))

I'm at a loss for what to try next. Uninstall Chrome? That seems dramatic.

Comment: Are you sure of your diagnosis in the title, that it doesn't flush the cache? What you wrote later contradicts it. DNS resolves hostnames to IP addresses, you suggest you get an "*old hostname*" and this has nothing to do with DNS.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I cleared the browser cache ("Clear Browsing Data") and that seems to have corrected the issue. I'm still somewhat confused how this issue came about but I jumped the gun blaming the Chrome DNS